# Get C++ RTTI as enum for dispatch in switch statement

Tags: c++, rtti

Is it possible to get an compiletime enum id from the C++ rtti type_info ? I want to use it in a switch statement for dispatching on a type *without* first going through a hash. Is there some standard way of doing this? In pseudocode something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
using namespace std;

struct base { virtual void f(void) = 0; };
struct a : public base { int v; void f(void) {}; };
struct b : public base { int v; void f(void) {}; };

void f(base *v) {

    switch(typeid(*v).hash_code()) {
        case comiletime_hash(typeid(a)):
            cout << "Is a\n";
        break;
        case comiletime_hash(typeid(b)):
            cout << "Is b\n";
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    a v0;
    b v1;
    f(&v0);
    f(&v1);

    return 0;
}
```

However `hash_code` is only available at runtime.

I want to find out weather I can use Rtti to rewrite some code from c:

```
  enum { typ1, typ2 ...}
  struct { int Tag; union { struct t1; struct t2;...}}
   ...
   switch (v->Tag) {
   case typ1: .... do something t1
   case typ2: ... do something t2
   ... }
```

I want to retain the switch statement. I'm not looking for a solution using `dynamic_cast` if-elseif cascade or a vitual functions.

Comment: Since `base` is polymorphic, `if(dynamic_cast<a *>(v))  ....` does check if `v` actually points to an `a`.

Comment: As the name suggests RTTI (run-time type information), it is only in run time. No way to get it in compile time. What do you want? If you could explain more may be someone would advise a better decision for your problem.

Comment: Interesting question. Until now I've assumed it's impossible (as described in above comment) and wrote the code for this manually. To find errors (e.g. new class added but not handled everywhere), the resp. `switch` statements always have a `default: assert(false);`.

Comment: `typeid(*v)` gives you the typeid for `base &`, because that's the type of the expression

Comment: @Yuki : Added my usecase, which is basically finding an equivalent construct from that of c.

Comment: @Peter : I know about the possibility to use dynamic_cast but that doesn’t scale and gets unreadable. I was hoping that there is some way to use switch...

Comment: Do you know Visitor pattern? That is for the thing you are exactly trying to achieve. Of course, it requires a little of design. If polymorphism is not the essence of your design you can go just with function overloading, i.e. have `f` function overloads for each type and pass the original type pointer to them.

Comment: @KonradEisele - if you are explicitly trying to check the type of an object against a set of possibilities, that doesn't scale either.     You need to use a design (or design pattern) that doesn't rely on working out the actual type of an object at run time.

Comment: @Yuki: thanks, yes I know these possibilities. I’m rewriting C code and I would need to change the structure of the code (lots of work). I was hoping for some tricks. The Rtti struct is maybe accessible via name whose link address can be used as int in switch, or something similar. Otherwise the answer is that it is not possible...

Comment: @Peter : ok thank. I‘ll look what kind of code dynamic_cast  actually generated with gcc. Maybe that leads me to something...

Comment: @KonradEisele - You've missed my point completely.   But I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler generates `std::type_info` for each type independently of other types. There is no unique compile-time enum/integer for each class.

You probably need to add another virtual function to your hierarchy that would obviate the need to use that switch statement at all. Or use [*visitor pattern*](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/visitor.html).

Alternatively, try [Open and Efficient Type Switch for C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3449.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, the visitor pattern in not what I want to use. It bears too much structural overhead for my case. I want to do a lot of different operations dependent on type in a lot of locations. The code would be unreadable. It seams that there is no way and the best is like it is done in c: implement it with an explicit int that all types share.

Comment: @KonradEisele Added an extra solution for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through it. This  seems maybe what I looked for.

Comment: Would be really nice to have it as a language feature. The implemenation https://github.com/solodon4/Mach7 as a library is really complicated and hard to follow. As far as I can see C<type>() create a match against the runtime object's vtable layout using complicated templating. The Match-Case creates a special switch-case statement that can lean on previous matches. If there would be a more simplistic implementation it would maybe suite my needs. I might better stick with "Simple solutions for simple problems"  instead. But thanks for the interestin read.

Answer (score 1):

A little trick, how to create static information about types so that you can compare them quickly with one switch statically or dynamically in C++11.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
    int m_ClassID;
    Base(int _id) : m_ClassID(_id) {} // dynamic classID
};

template<int N>
struct Base_ : Base {
    static constexpr int g_ClassID = N; // static classID
    Base_() : Base(N) {}
};

struct A : Base_<2222> // define ClassID
{};

struct B  : Base_<3333> // define ClassID
{};

void DoForAnyBase(Base* pBase) {
    switch(pBase->m_ClassID) {
        case A::g_ClassID:
        printf("I'm A");
        break;
        case B::g_ClassID:
        printf("I'm B");
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector< Base* > aTypes;
    aTypes.push_back( new A() );
    aTypes.push_back( new B() );

    for( Base* pCur : aTypes) {
        DoForAnyBase(pCur);
        delete pCur;
    }
}
```